# How to use regular urls without the hash symbol in spine.js?

Tags: spine.js

I'm trying to achieve urls in the form of http://localhost:9294/users instead of http://localhost:9294/#/users

This seems possible according to the documentation but I haven't been able to get this working  for "bookmarkable" urls.

To clarify, browsing directly to http://localhost:9294/users gives a 404 "Not found: /users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following rewrites as explained in this article.

http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on HTML5 History support in Spine like this:

`Spine.Route.setup(history: true)`

By passing the `history: true` argument to `Spine.Route.setup()` that will enable the fancy URLs without hash.

The documentation for this is actually buried a bit, but it's here (second to last section): http://spinejs.com/docs/routing

**EDIT:**

In order to have urls that can be navigated to directly, you will have to do this "server" side. For example, with Rails, you would have to build a way to take the parameter of the url (in this case "/users"), and pass it to Spine accordingly. Here is an excerpt from the Spine docs:

> However, there are some things you need to be aware of when using the
>   History API. Firstly, every URL you send to navigate() needs to have a
>   real HTML representation. Although the browser won't request the new
>   URL at that point, it will be requested if the page is subsequently
>   reloaded. In other words you can't make up arbitrary URLs, like you
>   can with hash fragments; every URL passed to the API needs to exist.
>   One way of implementing this is with server side support.
>
> When browsers request a URL (expecting a HTML response) you first make
>   sure on server-side that the endpoint exists and is valid. Then you
>   can just serve up the main application, which will read the URL,
>   invoking the appropriate routes. For example, let's say your user
>   navigates to http://example.com/users/1. On the server-side, you check
>   that the URL /users/1 is valid, and that the User record with an ID of
>   1 exists. Then you can go ahead and just serve up the JavaScript
>   application.
>
> The caveat to this approach is that it doesn't give search engine
>   crawlers any real content. If you want your application to be
>   crawl-able, you'll have to detect crawler bot requests, and serve them
>   a 'parallel universe of content'. That is beyond the scope of this
>   documentation though.

It's definitely a good bit of effort to get this working properly, but it CAN be done. It's not possible to give you a specific answer without knowing the stack you're working with.

Comment: I've read the docs so I'm aware of this already. I'm not sure that it applies in every situation since a route might not be related to a RESTful resource. In the case of Apache, what could be a potential solution?

Comment: You could probably come up with some sort of rewrite rule to pass the arguments of the route "/post/1" and redirect all traffic to an index page with something like ?route=/post/1. You would then have to interpret those arguments from spine and show the appropriate route. I would suggest you keep all your routing logic inside your application and stay away from doing a rewrite rule in Apache.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a more specific answer.

Comment: If you can provide more details of what your stack looks like, it will make it a lot easier to get a specific way of achieving this. Knowing exactly what your stack looks like (is it a Spine app served using Rails? A self contained Spine app bundled with Hem?) will help you get a better answer.

Comment: Right now it's a self contained app via "hem build" with Apache and a NoSQL database.